# How to install mullvad VPN using terminal on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, system-installation, software-installation, vpn, update-manager

Please help with the right commands again to try and install the latest version of mullvad VPN for ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

This command will always grab the latest ([source](https://mullvad.net/en/help/installs-mullvad-app-linux/)):

```bsh
wget --content-disposition https://mullvad.net/download/app/deb/latest
sudo apt install -y ./Mullvad*
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of mullvad VPN:

Open a terminal and run:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://mullvad.net/media/app/MullvadVPN-2020.6_amd64.deb
```

Install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i MullvadVPN-2020.6_amd64.deb
```